# Making a Windows path useful in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

If I copy a Windows path (say, "C:\foo\bar\bat") to the Windows Clipboard, I can paste it into an Emacs buffer, but can't do much else with it, as the backslashes are apparently interpreted as escapes. What can I do to make the string parseable in Emacs Lisp?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the backslashes to be interpreted as a backslash you should use double backslashes

i.e. 

```
("C:\\foo\\bar\\bat")
```

Comment: Would that I could, except that copying a path from the address field of a window in Windows Explorer, say with Ctrl-C, doesn't give one that opportunity (short of stopping to do a manual edit, which sort of defeats the purpose).

Comment: Add this to your `.emacs`, maybe bind it to a convenient key.  `(defun paste-windows-path (pth) (interactive "*sWindows path:") (insert (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\" "\\\\\\\\" pth)))`

Comment: ... or even code it to fetch and insert the contents of the system clipboard.  I'm not on Windows so I'm not sure if `x-get-selection` would be the way to get the clipboard contents.